# JAVA How to continually book/add a seat in a 2D cinema matrix that also displays the updated booked seats?

Tags: java

I am doing a Cinema Room booking manager.

The program inputs a row and a column that displays the size of the Cinema. For eg. Row 5, Column 5.

```
  1 2 3 4 5
1 S S S S S
2 S S S S S
3 S S S S S
4 S S S S S
5 S S S S S
```

Then, the program asked the user to select a seat in a form of a row and column (Eg. row 2, seat 5. Then once entered it will update the cinema matrix with the chosen seat 'B'

```
  1 2 3 4 5
1 S S S S S
2 S S S S B
3 S S S S S
4 S S S S S
5 S S S S S
```

Then, the goal is to be able to book more seats and it'll add then display more 'B' in the 2D matrix.

```
  1 2 3 4 5
1 B S S S S
2 S S S S B
3 S B S S S
4 S S S B S
5 S S S S S
```

Now, my program only displays the latest seat without saving the previous seats.
May I know what I can add to my existing code to be able to do that?

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cinema {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Write your code here
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int chosenRow = 0;
    int chosenColumn = 0;

    //Prices
    int priceLessThan60pax = 10;
    int priceFirstHalf = 10;
    int priceSecondHalf = 8;


    //Enter Cinema Size
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows:");
    int row = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of seats in each row");
    int column = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    int numberOfSeats = row * column;

    //Prompt menu
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("1: Show the seats");
        System.out.println("2. Buy a ticket");
        System.out.println("0. Exit");

        int menuSelection = scanner.nextInt();


        switch (menuSelection) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Cinema:");

                //Header ROW
                System.out.print("  ");
                for (int i = 1; i <= column; i++) {
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();

                for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                    for (int j = 0; j < column ; j++) {
                        if ((chosenRow == i) && (chosenColumn == j + 1)) {
                            System.out.print('B' + " ");
                        } else
                            System.out.print('S' + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println();
                break;
            case 2:
                //Select seat
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Enter a row number:");
                chosenRow = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter a seat number in that row:");
                chosenColumn = scanner.nextInt();

                //Determine price according to seat selection
                if (numberOfSeats > 60) {
                    if (chosenRow <= (row / 2)) {
                        System.out.println("Ticket Price: $" + priceFirstHalf);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Ticket Price: $" + priceSecondHalf);
                    }
                } else if (numberOfSeats < 60 ) {
                    System.out.println("Ticket Price: $" + priceLessThan60pax);
                }
                System.out.println();
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having here is that you overwrite the last chosen row / column each time a user selects a new one:

```
chosenRow = scanner.nextInt();
```

There are 2-3 obvious solutions:

- store a `list` of already booked seats using their row/column coordinates. This works well for szenarios, where you have only few items to store compared to the overall grid size, e.g. when the cinema is usually nearly empty. This approach is pretty flexible, e.g. a cinema having "vip seats" using up double the space might be implemented pretty easily here.
- create an `array` of `arrays` containing `Booleans`, with the size rows/columns. Initialize it with `false` and change to `true`, when the seat is booked. This works well for szenarios, where you expect lots of items compared to the grid size (fully booked cinema). It also wrks well when a very common usecase is checking "is seat x available" (in contrast to just list all available seats): checking "is array[5][6] booked" is a O(1) operation, while "find the seat 5/6 in a list" may take significantly longer, up to O(n), if the list isn't sorted. See also [Landau-Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)
- mixing both approaches. E.g. create an `array` for each row containing a `list` storing each booked seat in that row.